# How to display new line as a special char in text area

Tags: css, textarea

I have a text area where user inputs some commands. I want to display new line as a special char, say . This might enable the user to understand where all the new lines are there.

I am using angular. Below is the snippet where i am supposed to add this.

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=30
    style="color: #008000; overflow: scroll;" class="form-control"
    ng-model="instructionset.payload_plain" placeholder="title">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS-only answer, or is JaqvaScript permitted too?

Comment: I am fine with anything actually.